# How to write a txt file all in one line from dataframe

Tags: r, write.table

I have the following dataframe (data6):

```
1   41595370       1    1   OV1
2   41595371       1    1   OV2
3   41595282       1    1   OV3
4   41595282       2    1   OV3
```

I would like to write it to txt file that all of the lines are in one line like this:

```
41595370 1 1 OV1 41595371 1 1 OV2 41595282 1 1 OV3 41595282 2 1 OV3
```

When I use the following command:

> write.table(data6, file = "C:/MyData.txt",row.names=FALSE, na="",col.names=FALSE, sep=",")

I get the following `TXT` content:

```
41595370,1,1,"OV1"
41595371,1,1,"OV2"
41595282,1,1,"OV3"
41595282,2,1,"OV3"
41595373,1,1,"OV4"
```

How can I get the one line `TXT` file format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `eol` parameter in `write.table()` to `eol=""` otherwise R automatically inserts a newline character:

```
data6 = data.frame(subid = c(41595370, 41595371, 41595282, 41595282), rep=c(1,1,1,2), machine = 1, operator = c('OV1', 'OV2', 'OV3', 'OV4'))


write.table(data6, "C:/MyData.txt", eol="", quote=F, row.names=F, col.names=F)
```

writes a line to file that looks like:
41595370 1 1 OV141595371 1 1 OV241595282 1 1 OV341595282 2 1 OV4

Comment: Stedy Thanks a lot. In case I would like that there won't be space between each line such as:
41595370 1 1 OV141595371 1 1 OV241595282 1 1 OV341595282 2 1 OV3
What do I have to change in write.table?